# how do you copy a url into variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to copy a url that looks like this: `http://domain.com/myfile.php?test-main`

So I'm trying to get the url so I can add variable r to the end like so: `http://domain.com/myfile.php?test-main?r=stuff`

When I use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` it just copies the file name myfile.php and not the other variables. Any one how I can copy the entire url?

Comment: If you `echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SERVER, true) . '</pre>';`, you can see all of the variables you have access to in the `$_SERVER` array. One of them will contain your entire URL. See if you can find it. :)

Comment: `var_dump($_SERVER);` and see if there's something useful there

Comment: @user962449: "copy" a url, where from?

Comment: the answer by 'genesis φ appears correct, but please look in the manual next time first. the behaviour you're getting is no surprise but perfectly specified: http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$addr = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']."&r=stuff";
```

And you might want to filter variables for a possible XSS attack

Comment: if i want to pass $addr var with php, when i echo it in the second page i get the url only till &. all the variables after the sign & are gone. what should i do?

Answer (score -1):

Build it yourself out of the provided parts.

Do a print_r($_SERVER); to see all available

The main one you want to add is HTTP_HOST